# Objective-C Pointer to class that implements a protocol

Tags: objective-c, polymorphism

I have three classes which implement the same protocol, and have the same parent class which doesn't implement the protocol.  Normally I would have the protocol as pure virtual functions in the parent class but I couldn't find an Objective-C way to do that.

I want to utilize polymorphism on these subclasses by declaring pure virtual functions in the superclass then have the children implement those functions.  However the only Objective-C way I've found to do this is to have each child explicitly decide to implement a protocol, when I do it this way the superclass doesn't know the children will implement that protocol so there are compile time warnings all over the place.

Some pseudo-code if that didn't make sense:

```
@interface superclass: NSObject
{}

@interface child1: superclass<MyProtocol>
{}

@interface child2: superclass<MyProtocol>
{}
```

The consumer of these classes:

```
@class child1
@class child2
@class superclass

@interface SomeViewController: UIViewController
{
    child1 *oneView;
    child2 *otherView;
    superclass *currentView;
}

-(void) someMethod
{
    [currentView protocolFunction];
}
```

The only nice way I've found to do pure virtual functions in Objective-C is a hack by putting `[self doesNotRecognizeSelector:_cmd];` in the parent class, but it isn't ideal since it will cause runtime errors rather than compile time.

Comment: It seems like the ObjC way of pure-virtual / abstract methods is "class clusters". Might be something worth investigating for you.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I was able to get the compiler to warn me correctly by making the `superclass *currentView` property look like this:

```
@property (nonatomic, retain) superclass<MyProtocol> *currentView;
```

Answer (score 11):

Objective-C developers commonly use dynamic checking rather than compile-time checking in these situations because the language and the frameworks support it so well. So for example, you could write your method like this:

```
- (void)someMethod
{
    // See if the object in currentView conforms to MyProtocol
    //
    if ([currentView conformsToProtocol:@protocol(MyProtocol)])
    {
        // Cast currentView to the protocol, since we checked to make
        // sure it conforms to it. This keeps the compiler happy.
        //
        [(SuperClass<MyProtocol> *) currentView protocolMethod];
    }
}
```

Comment: Of course, it's more reliable to use `respondsToSelector:@selector(protocolMethod)`.

Comment: ...and necessary if the protocol has optional methods.

Comment: I wouldn't encourage using run-time type information like this - it is very unlikely to be a genuine case where you don't know the type of your object well enough at compile time to avoid doing this. Most common cases where I've seen RTTI used are redundant with a bit of thought. The exception is implementing generics type code in Objective-C where, sadly, we are forced to use a fundamentally less efficient mechanism than the compiler is able to generate code for, simply because there are no compile-time generics in the language spec (a problem shared with/inherited from C). Also, remote exec

Comment: I think that we Objective-C programmers don't use dynamic type checking because "the frameworks supports it so well", we use it because the static type checking system isn't sufficiently expressive to forgo it.

Answer (score 3):

Alternatively you can use the following

```
if ([unknownObject conformsToProtocol:@protocol(MyProtocol)])
   [unknownObject performSelector:@selector(methodInProtocol)];
```

instead of the following if you just want to suppress the warning.

```
if ([unknownObject conformsToProtocol:@protocol(MyProtocol)])
   [unknownObject methodInProtocol];  // will cause warning
```

performSelector: will only work if the number of arguments is zero or one. More flexible invocations can be achieved with NSInvocation.

Answer (score 1):

Personally, I would implement the protocol on the super class, but implement the methods like this:

```
- (id) myProtocolMethod {
  NSAssert(NO, [NSString stringWithFormat:@"-[%@ %@] must be overridden", NSStringFromClass([self class]), NSStringFromSelector(_cmd)]);
  return nil;
}
```

That way if you ever forget to override a method in a concrete subclass, it should be immediately obvious.

Comment: It depends whether all subclasses should conform to the protocol; not really sure what Winder has in mind there. But I'm definitely not putting those asserts in my production code. I'd rather just provide empty methods, and maybe log a warning.

Comment: In fact, I was going to suggest sort of the opposite: consider making the protocol methods optional, and do the runtime check, but again, it really depends what the intent is.

Comment: This is the behavior I want, just with a compiler error rather than a runtime one.  It doesn't look like Objective-C has a way to do this though.